# JSON Array not loading completely?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I've been running into a error lately where I am trying to filter a array but at times when I log the whole array (before any filtering) the array is missing items. This happens when I call this function multiple times, is there a work around for this?

[image: array error]

This is the code for filtering the array, I used .find() as proposed but the original data is still being overwritten:

```js
let newData = dataCorte
// Log variables 
console.log('Type:',args.tipo);
// Log the WHOLE ARRAY, it has two items ALWAYS
console.log('Original Data:', dataCorte.e);
// Filter the array into a new variable
let found = newData.e.find(item => {
                return item.id === args.tipo
            })
// Log the WHOLE ARRAY, it has two items ALWAYS
 console.log('Original Data:', dataCorte.e);
// Assign the found object into the 'e' array
 newData.e = [found]

console.log('================================');
// Return the new data
return newData
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using .filter() to get one value while you should've used .find():

```
let data = dataCorte.e.find(item => {
  return item.id === args.tipo
}); //no need to use [0] since it will return one object
```

That will be safer since you already fetching one value and it won't mess with your array.

when you assign `dataCorte` to `newData` which assigned by reference not by value, which means both are referring to the same location in the memory. To solve this you need to make a work around to copy the array instead of passing it by reference:

```
// "Spread"
let newData = { ...dataCorte }


// "Object.assign"
let newData = Object.assign({}, dataCorte)


// "JSON"
let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataCorte))
```

Comment: I just did, but the original array is still being modified D:

Comment: @Jeremy I've updated my answer to include how to solve this assignment at the beginning of your code.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the array inside the original object and then return the  whole object. I already tried: 
`let newData = dataCorte.e.slice()`
 but it won't work since I need to access the property with the array and filter it

Comment: I think you did not get what i meant. when you later assign `newData.e = [found]` it also affects `dataCorte` so if you can `return [found]` without the prior assignment then that will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I know I can return the `found` array with .`find()` , but I need to return this whole Object for a GraphQL query so I can't just return the array. Thank you so much in advance haha

Comment: Aah. Isee. I was confused to think that `dataCorte` is an array while it's actually an object. Check this link to clone objects: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/70-3-ways-to-clone-objects

Answer (score 0):

I found this fixes the problem noted by [MEDZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125339/medz) which I found [here](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript):

```js
// Create a copy of dataCorte
let newData = Object.assign({}, dataCorte)
 // Log variables 
console.log('Type:',args.tipo);
// Log the WHOLE ARRAY, it has two items ALWAYS
console.log('Original Data:', dataCorte.e.slice());
// Filter the array into a new variable
console.log('Filtering for item');

let found = dataCorte.e.find(item => {
                return item.id === args.tipo
            })
// Log the WHOLE ARRAY, it has two items ALWAYS
console.log('Original Data:', dataCorte.e);
 // Assign the found object into the 'e' array
newData.e = [found]

console.log('================================');
// Return the new data
return newData
```